# How can i add random value using jmeter in Json

Tags: jmeter

I am testing an API using JMeter.

But if I have sent multiple requests it's not working because of `user_id` show duplicate.

In the Test plan, I add a variable and define value.

Using BeanShell PostProcessor I try to make generate random value.

But all time as I define value not update the random value.

```
{

  "user": {

    "user_id": 100113,

    "rest_id": 4589445,

    "rest_name": "chetan",

    }

}
```

Using HTTP header manager and HTTP Request.
In HTTP Request body I passed this JSON

For a single request, it's working fine.
But if I have sent multiple requests it's not working because of `user_id` show duplicate.
how can I change every time user_id with the help of JMeter?
Right now I am doing manually. Every time I have to change `user_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this random function ${__RandomString(6,1236547890,)}. It will generate random value of 6 digit each time.

For more details visit below link:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Comment: Thanks but when writing this function only one time it generates a random value.

Comment: Where you are writing this code? I hope it is like this-
{

  "user": {

    "user_id": ${__RandomString(6,1236547890,)},

    "rest_id": 4589445,

    "rest_name": "chetan",

    }

}

And run the sampler multiple time. It will generate random value each time the request hits.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSV Data sec config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to parameterize user id. Input userids in csv then pass the **column name** of the csv in the json as   "user_id": ${USERIDFROMCSV}

For more info on csv data set config use, check link:-
https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG

Also, there are functions which can be used like Random,RandomString. For more information check:-
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

you could be to work with Random Variable, an element available in JMeter’s config elements:

Thread group -> Add -> Config Element -> Random Variable
[image]

jmeter, random variable element

The sampler looks like this:

jmeter , load testing, random variable sampler

Setting it as follows:

[image]

then call in the body or url the random variable using ${random}

[Link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/random-variables-in-jmeter)